# why are sbt moving to AutoPlugin?

Tags: sbt, sbt-plugin

I've recently been informed that my sbt plugins don't work using the magical new "Auto Plugin" feature, which is the recommended mechanism.

1. why are sbt doing this?
2. will all plugins have to be updated?
3. will it support sonatype snapshot releases?

I've been informed by one of our users that snapshots are not supported but I cannot find a definitive answer on this. We will have serious problems as we use rolling releases between stable releases.

In my opinion, it would be a disaster if sbt expects all authors to make changes to support this. The real value in sbt is that there are so many plugins for it, and if changes are made that exclude some of those plugins then we all suffer.

Answer (score 4):

1. Because it means you can just add the plugin to your plugins.sbt file and the plugin will take care of configuring itself. You won't need to do `instrumentSettings` or whatever in your build.sbt anymore. It will also import the keys automatically. Finally, the plugin can control under which scenarios its activated (triggers). If you're happy with the defaults, you need not do anything further.
2. No, if you don't update your plugin will simply continue to be a "non-auto plugin". My plugin for scoverage is not an auto plugin it and won't be for a while
3. The concept of auto plugin is nothing to do with if you use a snapshot version or a release version of a specific plugin.